# Unicode glyph to represent "font color" in a toolbar?

Tags: unicode

I am looking for a Unicode character that looks like a "select font color" icon.

I have searched and I found image which is 
[image]

But I can not find Unicode value. I want to use that code as Metro button source.

**Edit:**

For Example [image]

Unicode value is 0x3E same way I want unicode for.
Given Image.Given Image can be set to AppBar Button to Choose Color of any Control. But I anm unable to set images. I want Unicode value that can set as constant of button which will display as Image in view.

Comment: do you mean `Foreground='White'`? but i doesn't get the link between Font color and Unicode in XAML

Comment: Unicode value 0x3E is unambiguously “>” U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN. You seem to be using a privately encoded font that contains glyphs that do not correspond to any Unicode character. The proper way to use such glyphs is to use Private Use codepoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't thing there  is one. Most Win8 chars you can find in `Segoe UI Symbol` font, which is shipped with Windows 8 (the one from Win7 is a little different). You can download and embed it into your application.

From `Segoe UI Symbol` you can use the   [image] character (Unicode hex - `E186`) and display it inside an [Ellipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse.aspx).

Also check out this post: [Windows 8 Icons](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2012/03/windows-8-icons-segoe-ui-symbol.html).

Comment: thanx for reply but it displaying as box in my view and i can't find  this character in character map also..

Comment: I got it from Character Map, make sure to look into Segoe UI Symbol (Windows 8) you can find it on net if you don't have windows 8 installed.

Comment: i have windows 7 installed.. and if u have window8 installed can u tell me the unicode value..

Comment: The hex value from above post is used to find the address where the character resides within a specific `FontFamily`. If you don't have the `Font` installed and you don't want to embed it in your app you can't use the characters. Read the link about the Windows 8 Icons.

Answer (score 2):

There is none. There isn’t even any Unicode character that you could reasonably use to symbolize change of color.

Unicode encodes characters, not glyphs. Unicode characters have no inherent color (their color will be set by the rendering engine, possibly under the control of a style sheet, for example), except for some emoji characters in a sense. And glyphs normally have no inherent color either.

Generally, you should not expect icons to be encoded as characters in Unicode. Some are, for various reasons, but mostly an icon is a specific graphic appearance and lacks the normal “characterhood” of a Unicode character – normally a character is expected to have different shapes in different fonts.

A suitable icon for changing color is one that contains a few colors. E.g., a circle split in three or four segments, each with distinguishably different color. It’s a job for an image, not for a character.